# WSO2 - Enterprise integrator 6.5.0 Tenant name validation error received as soap message

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I am calling a enterprise integrator tenant by URL: /t/tenant.domain
When the tenant name is not valid, a soap message is received as follows:

```
<soapenv:Reason xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soapenv:Text xml:lang="en-US">Error while getting tenant activation status.</soapenv:Text>
</soapenv:Reason>
```

However, my api is JSON REST API, how to tell WSO2 to return this error as json? and which component exactly is returning it?
Note: i tried to change the content type and accept to application/json but i still receive an XML message.

Answer (score 0):

This error is coming from the carbon core, specifically from this [line](https://github.com/wso2/carbon-kernel/blob/4.5.x/core/org.wso2.carbon.core/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/core/multitenancy/utils/TenantAxisUtils.java#L126) in the source. This is kind of a bug IMO as it throws a `RuntimeException` due to a `NullPointer` when trying to check the tenant status in the DB.

Having said that, there is no easy way out, either you will have to customize the source and patch the product to produce a JSON or you may have to handle this externally. For example, if you are not creating tenants frequently you can consider handling this in your Load balancer. Define context mappings for all the existing tenants and have a default context mapping for non-existing tenants which will respond with a proper JSON message with an HTTP 404 status.